# Reactjs - Submitting multiple lines from one textarea

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms, textarea, multiple-instances

I'm trying to allow a textarea to take a list of names and display the submission of names on the page. However, I want the user to only be able to submit one name per line.

How would one go about this? More specifically, how would one grab the line breaks and split them into, say... an array to be mapped through and displayed in a dom element.

In my code the state of *names* is an empty string, but I think it would be easier/more manageable if it were an array.

Thanks!

```js
class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: ""
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      names: e.target.value
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="flex">
        <div className="content flex">

          <div className="sandbox flex">
            <div className="directions">
              <h1>Please enter a list of names.</h1>
              <h3>Select a langauge at the top of the page.</h3>
            </div>

            <form id="nameForm" className="names flex">
              <div className="form-group">
                <textarea
                  id="names"
                  name="hard"
                  value={this.state.names}
                  cols={20}
                  rows={20}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  wrap="hard">
                </textarea>
              </div>
            </form>

            <button id="formButton" form="nameForm" type="submit">Submit</button>

            <div className="nametags flex">
              <div className="nametags-group flex">
                <button type="button" className="nametag">{this.state.names}</button>
                <p className="greeting">Hello there, happy to see you back!</p>
              </div>
              <div className="nametags-group flex">
                <button type="button" className="nametag">John Doe</button>
                <p className="greeting">Hello there, happy to see you back!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work perfectly for you:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      names: ''
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit = name => {
    alert(`Submitted name: ${name}`)
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      names: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="flex">
        <div className="content flex">
          <div className="sandbox flex">
            <div className="directions">
              <h1>Please enter a list of names.</h1>
              <h3>Select a langauge at the top of the page.</h3>
            </div>

            <form id="nameForm" className="names flex">
              <div className="form-group">
                <textarea
                  id="names"
                  name="hard"
                  value={this.state.names}
                  cols={20}
                  rows={20}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  wrap="hard"
                />
              </div>
            </form>

            <button id="formButton" form="nameForm" type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>

            <div className="nametags flex">
              <div className="nametags-group flex">
                {this.state.names
                  .split('\n')
                  .filter(n => n) // to filter out empty names
                  .map((name, index) => (
                    <button
                      key={index}
                      type="button"
                      className="nametag"
                      onClick={() => this.handleSubmit(name)}
                    >
                      {name}
                    </button>
                  ))}
                <p className="greeting">Hello there, happy to see you back!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Content
```

I think it's easier to keep the `name` state as string.
When rendering the names, split the string at `\n`, filter out the empty names (basically those extra newlines without names), and render the rest.

When clicking on those name buttons, call handleSubmit and pass `name` as argument.

So the rest to do is what you want to do with those names in `handleSubmit`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    names: e.target.value,
    submitNames: e.target.value.split(/\r?\n/)
  });
};
```

And change how you display buttons:

```
{ this.state.submitNames.map(
   (name) => 
     <button
       onClick={() => this.handleSubmit(name)}
       type="button" 
       className="nametag"
     >
      {name}
     </button>
)}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I actually just tried this method and it works great. as for the button your mentioning, it just a UI button with no use. However the submit button for the form has use.